# Infusionsoft Getting Tags

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am new to the Infusion API and I have a couple of questions that I am unable to find a specific answer to.

I have used the PHP SDK and installed via composer

1) Within the new API is there away that I can view all tags that have been created?

2) I have created and got my client `clientId` and `clientSecret` via but I am unsure how I connect it to the app name that I want to fetch the tags for.

I have given it an attempt by looking at code examples I have seen via Google however I am getting the following error - `Call to undefined method Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft::dsQuery()`

**Code:**

```
<?php

//Connect to the Infusionsoft API

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$infusionsoft = new \Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft(array(
    'clientId'      => 'key',
    'clientSecret'  => 'key',

    ));

// Fetch the required tags for this place

$getFields = array('Id','GroupDescription', 'GroupName');
$query     = array('GroupName' => '%');
$tags      = $infusionsoft->dsQuery("ContactGroup",1000,0,$query,$getFields);

var_dump($tags);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, there's no new API. Improvements are added to Infusionsoft API all the time, but it's still the same updated API. If you mean new  [Infusionsoft PHP SDK](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php), then example request to get the tags looks this way:

`$infusionsoft->data()->query('ContactGroup', $limit, $page, $queryData, $selectedFields, $orderBy, $ascending);`

*query()* method is implemented in [Infusionsoft/Api/DataService.php file](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php/blob/master/src/Infusionsoft/Api/DataService.php)

2. You connect to a specific Infusionsoft account during oAuth authorization flow. This basic flow is shown, for example, in [PHP SDK examples](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php/tree/master/samples)

The error you see means exactly what it says - there's no such method *dsQuery()* in the updated SDK. The link to the SDK code where you can see all available methods was provided in the first point.